# from a import b in python 2.4

Tags: python, python-import

Need help with import in python 2.4

The problem statement is:

```
src\
__init__.py
main.py
dirFoo\
__init__.py
Foo.py
dirBar\
__init__.py
Bar.py
```

I need to access main.py in Foo.py

The version of python is 2.4.3. Its much easier in python > 2.5. But I am a hard time in 2.4

Answer (score 0):

A simple absolute import (i.e. `import src.main`) should work regardless of Python version.

However, there are a few things that would help clarify your question.

1. Is the source layout flat (as currently shown in the question) or nested (as shown below):

   ```
   src\
       __init__.py
       main.py
       dirFoo\
           __init__.py
           Foo.py
       dirBar\
           __init__.py
           Bar.py
   ```
2. Exactly what error do you get for `import src.main` from the interpreter prompt?
3. What error do you get for `import src.main` in `Foo.py`?
4. What are you actually running from the command line? Are you importing `src.dirFoo.Foo` from another script, or are you actually attempting to execute `"python src/dirFoo/Foo.py"` directly?

Comment: 'src' is a weird package name

Comment: Yes I've been trying this, it says invalid module name src

Comment: I've added a few clarifying questions to my answer. I'm not sure your current question is actually getting at the heart of whatever is causing your problem.

Comment: python -msrc.main (Error: python: module src.main not found)

Comment: Ah, you're hitting a completely different problem then - the `-m` switch in Python 2.4 only supports top-level modules, it can't handle packages (as you've seen).

Comment: As a workaround for Python 2.4, you can use the original recipe from the Python Cookbook: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/307772-executing-modules-inside-packages-with-m/?in=user-2035254